# Copy table from one server to another using select statement

Tags: sql-server

I need to copy a table from one server to another.for that I have did the below code,

```
select * into tbls from SNRJDI-32962\xxxmanagement.master.dbo.tbl
```

When I execute I got error Like,

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

but this is the actual server name(SNRJDI-32962\xxxmanagement)..Please do needful..

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first have to add a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) from the target server to the source server.

Then you can use a four-part name, separated by dots:

```
select * into [newtable] from [linked_server].[databasename].dbo.[tablename]
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working it just ask me to Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers.

Comment: @Andomar what about the credentials ? I mean both server are different and user also also different then how should i deals with it ? and from which server credentials i have to provide ?

Comment: When you create a linked server, there are many security options to choose from. If you have a question about those you'd better ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Andomar's answer that to have special characters in an object name, you need to surround the name in [square brackets] otherwise sql will interpret your "-" as a minus sign